# Use dynamic column name in Apply query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where I need to check authorization in DB. However the authorization field contains comma-separated values. So, to extract and add a where clause I used CROSS-APPLY, as demonstrated at [split-comma-separated-list](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/04/21/sql-server-split-comma-separated-list-without-using-a-function/), which is working fine.

The query goes something like

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Certs
FROM
(
SELECT EmployeeID,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Certs,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM some_table
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

Later I need to get the column "Certs" dynamically from another table. So, I added one more select with it to get the column name. But when I write that in REPLACE function, it returns the value i.e. column name. I need to treat it as a column name and get the values corresponding to it.

The modified query looks like

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Certs
(SELECT DatabaseColumnName FROM column_name_table WHERE ID = 98) YY ---Returns "Certs"
CROSS APPLY
FROM
(
SELECT EmployeeID,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(YY.DatabaseColumnName,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM some_table
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you want to choose a column name dynamically and get that value for your query. To do that, you need to use dynamic sql, and you need to be very careful with dynamic sql to avoid sql injection if this code is exposed to user input. It's hard to offer an answer without more information about your tables, sample data, and desired results, and how this code would be used. For more on dynamic sql, start here:  [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: @SqlZim: security issue is not a problem in my case as we don't get anything from user in this case. You are right by the way. I may need to use dynamic sql. But I am creating this as a where clause statement. So, the sql statement will be added to a where clause with IN or something. For that matter I wish to avoid dynamic variable and do it in query it self.

Comment: @SqlZim I tried with dynamic variable. Even if I use that, the replace function is still considering it as a string, not a column name. If there is any alternatives for the replace function, it could help !!

Answer (score 0):

Repeating my earlier comment: you need to use dynamic sql, and you need to be very careful with dynamic sql to avoid sql injection if this code is exposed to user input.

If the `DatabaseColumnName` will be the same for all `EmployeeID`, then you can get that column name and concatenate it to the executed sql like so:

```
declare @col sysname;
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select @col = DatabaseColumnName from column_name_table where id = 98);

set @sql = '
SELECT EmployeeID,
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value(''.[1]'',''varchar(8000)''))) AS '+@col+'
FROM
(
SELECT EmployeeID,CAST(''<XMLRoot><RowData>'' 
  + REPLACE('+@col+','','',''</RowData><RowData>'') 
  + ''</RowData></XMLRoot>'' AS XML) AS x
FROM some_table
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes(''/XMLRoot/RowData'')m(n)
'

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Dynamic Sql Reference:

- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
- [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

If you want more options for splitting strings other than the method you are using now:

Splitting Strings:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)